# credit note not appearing in dashboard but appears under contacts

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to create a credit note via the api. I can do this successfully and i can see the response it creates the record. How ever this does not appear in the business under invoices but i can see it under the contact. How can i fix this so it appears under the business on invoices

I am coding in PhP

```
$creditNote = new CreditNote();
        $creditNote->setType(CreditNote::TYPE_ACCPAYCREDIT);
        $creditNote->setContact($contact);
        $creditNote->setDate($model->created_at);
        $creditNote->setDueDate($model->created_at);
        $creditNote->setLineItems($lineItems);
        $creditNote->setCreditNoteNumber('GF-'.$model->number);
        $creditNote->setCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
        $creditNotes = new CreditNotes();
        $arr_credit_notes = [];
        array_push($arr_credit_notes, $creditNote);
        $creditNotes->setCreditNotes($arr_credit_notes);

        try {
            return $this->accountingApi->createCreditNotes(
                $this->xero_account->tenantId,
                $creditNotes,
                $summarizeErrors,
                $unitdp
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->debug($e);
            $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
            throw new CustomException(
                'Exception when calling AccountingApi->updateOrCreateCreditNotes: ' .
                $e->getMessage(),
                422
            );
        }
```

If I create a manual credit note in xero it appears in the business->invoices

in contact this is how it looks. Grren ones from api and the blue one i created in xero

[image: xero contact]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are creating the wrong type of credit note. "ACCPAYCREDIT" would show up under "bills to pay" rather than invoices. You would want to be creating an "ACCRECCREDIT" for it to show up under invoices